# I want to set a fixed width to a VStack but it doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to set a fixed width to a VStack but it doesn't work, the container wraps to the text and each box is independent for a list

This is the container:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        GeometryReader { container in
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: category)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .foregroundColor(.ez)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .frame(
                        width: (container.size.width * 0.2)
                    )

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    Text(detail)
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                    Text("Actualizada el \(date)")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                .frame(
                    width: (container.size.width * 0.7),
                    height: .infinity
                )

            }
            .padding(.all, 15)
        }
    }
    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 120)
    .background(Color.yellow)
    .clipped()
    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
    .cornerRadius(4.0)
    .shadow(radius: 2.0)
}
```

[image]

Here it will be displayed dynamically

Fixed size not respected

```
struct DashboardView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            FormView(category: "newspaper", title: "Inventario de material", detail: "Cartilla.", date: "01/07/2020")
            FormView(category: "newspaper", title: "Inventario de material", detail: "Cartilla de control de material y equipamiento para el trabajador.", date: "01/07/2020")
            FormView(category: "checkmark.shield.fill", title: "Programa de control", detail: "Cartilla de control de empleados en fábrica del mes de junio.", date: "01/07/2020")
            FormView(category: "bus.fill", title: "Urgente - Cartilla SBC", detail: "Encuesta para conocer la satisfacción de los clientes de EzForms en junio.", date: "01/07/2020")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you want the 0.2*width to come from? Is that from the screen width? Or the width of the yellow view in the screenshot?

Comment: the yellow view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly - never set a fixed size to `.infinity`. You can set `maxWidth`/`maxHeight`, but not `width`/`height`.

Next, I would structure it slightly differently. I would have the yellow view be the base - and the rest is an overlay. In the overlay is the `GeometryReader`, so you can know the size of the yellow view. The `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` helps the `GeometryReader` appropriately fill the space so the content is centered correctly.

Another change is that the `HStack` now contains a `Spacer()` - just a view that we can also set a width to, to space out the `Image` and `VStack`.

Code:

```
Color.yellow
    .frame(height: 120)
    .overlay(
        GeometryReader { geo in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: category)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)

                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.1)

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    Text(detail)
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                    Text("Actualizada el")// \(date)")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.7, alignment: .leading)
            }
            .padding(15)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    )
    .cornerRadius(4.0)
    .shadow(radius: 2.0)
    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
```

Result:

[image: Result]

You can adjust the widths as necessary, just make sure the ratios add up to `1`.

Comment: Thanks it works for me.